# Problems running: apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true

Tags: apt

I've followed the recommendations to force IPv4 but it doesn't work in my case.

That is what I get:

```
> sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
0% [Conectando a dl.google.com (64.233.190.91)] [Conectando a packages.linuxmint.com (68.235.39.11)] [Conectando a archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.149)]
```

And nothing else happens.

I also applied the changes mentioned in [this article](http://nickescobedo.com/719/ubuntu-apt-get-hangs-at-0) without results:

Comment: Is not your connection under a proxy?

Comment: Yes, my connection is under a proxy.

Comment: You must update proxy connections in your /etc/apt/apt.conf. You could do this by calling `network` app at Unity launcher and setting it there to Manual and filling fields.  Apply system wide and try `sudo apt-get`again.

Answer (score 2):

To enable proxy-connections to your computer, you must edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

There are two ways to do it:

**1. Unity:**
Launch *network* app at Unity launcher, follow as the picture shows:

[image]

**2. Terminal**

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, adding these lines (IP and port are just examples):

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://172.24.12.50:3128/";
```

If this proxy requires authentication, so you must change IP info with `user:password@ip:port`. e.g below:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://user:password@172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://user:password@172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://user:password@172.24.12.50:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://user:password@172.24.12.50:3128/";
```

If your network proxy is Microsoft NTLM-authenticated, as I've got here, then you must create a local-proxy to overcome it. I use [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/). It's in Universe repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've my proxy already configured. In fact, I've internet connection. Something else, I'm using Linux Mint 18.2 and there is not a apt.conf file. Intead of that, I've a etc/apt/apt.conf.d directory.

Comment: Create a file named 95proxies within this folder with the same contents.